# Hide 'Running X task' in grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-cli

I have been working on a project setup and deploy Gruntfile but would like to hide the command line output so that the following:

```
Running "init" task

Running "prompt:init" (prompt) task
[?] If you continue your project information will be overwritten.
    Continue? (Y/n)
```

becomes

```
[?] If you continue your project information will be overwritten.
    Continue? (Y/n)
```

when running grunt. I know it's only cosmetic but it's something I would like to do and cannot seem to find anything on Grunt's API documentation to indicate this can be done.

Comment: I would also like to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 4):

This is currently not supported, but possible thanks to the following workaround (from [shama](https://github.com/shama) on GitHub):

```
grunt.log.header = function () {};
```

Basically, this overrides the log header function (which is responsible for the "running x task" message) by an empty function that does nothing, and more importantly, outputs nothing.

There's another way to do it:

- First, run `npm install grunt-log-headers` to install [grunt-log-headers](https://github.com/stevenvachon/grunt-log-headers).
- Then add `require('grunt-log-headers')(grunt);` to your Gruntfile.js to enable it.
- Finally, add this to *any* task for which you want to hide the log header:

  ```
  options: {
      gruntLogHeader: false
  }
  ```

  Example:

  ```
  grunt.initConfig({
      sometask: {
          options: {
              gruntLogHeader: false,
          }
      }
  });
  ```

In fact, [an issue has already been created for this](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/895). It's currently being worked on, and will *normally* be available in the version 0.5.0.